# Probability density — odds of a tie in the California election

Tags: probability, approximation, binomial-distribution

Assume, as seems likely, in the 2024 presidential election, Californians will cast 20 million votes.  Make the simplifying assumption that that each Californian will vote Democrat with a probability of 60% (as they did in 2020).

What are the odds that California will *tie exactly*?  It is given by the formula
$$
f(k,n,p) = \mathbb{P}[X=k] = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}.
$$

$p = 0.6$, but unfortunately $n = 20,000,000$ and $k= 10,000,000$.

I know the value is “astronomical”, but I am trying to approximate it and am out of my depth.  Trying to use [Stirling’s approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), I get $0.48^{30,000,000}/\pi$, but I have no confidence in that.

Comment: $$\binom {2m}{m}\sim \frac{4^m}{\sqrt{m\pi}}$$ you should get about $$\frac1{2.6\cdot10^{177291}}$$